# What's the correct technique to access IP & TCP data from a netfilter-queued packet?

Tags: c, tcp, tcpdump, raw-sockets, netfilter

I am writing code to accept TCP connections on *any* port (without opening & listening on *all* ports) by queueing SYN packets to userspace via nftables, then binding a rendezvous socket to accept the connection before ACCEPTing the SYN packet.  This looks like it will work (although if there's a simpler alternative, please tell me!).

But I can't find docs or examples for how to access the various fields of a TCP/IP packet.  I'm using libmnl, and my program is based on a very-lightly-modified examples/netfilter/nf-queue.c.  When I access and dump the PAYLOAD, it looks like a TCP packet, and I am able to pull the destination port out by `peek`ing in the buffer (more or less).  However, I would like to access the packet fields in the proper way.

Is there documentation, a FAQ, or example code that can go from a `struct nlmsghdr *` to the `PAYLOAD` element to a TCP packet pointer, which will allow me to access things like `sport`, `dport`, flags, and so on?